# Dynamically updating list of unique column entries in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to extract all unique names in a list. Optimally, this would work like the FREQUENCY function, that returns an array (that can then be accessed via the INDEX function).

I know both PivotTables and the Advanced Filter can do this, but both don't update dynamically.

Is there a function I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this post on sorting and de-duping a list automatically without code:

[Building a self-sorting list Part 1](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/09/03/building-a-self-sorting-list/)
[Building a self-sorting list Part 2](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/09/06/building-a-self-sorting-list-part-2/)

Comment: +1 Be sure to read Part 2 for the complete instructions.

Answer (score 2):

From [this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ListFunctions.aspx). formula 1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,A2,"")
```

Enter it in B2 and do a fill down.

From [this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/noblanks.htm), formula 2:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW(NoBlanksRange)+1>ROWS(BlanksRange)-COUNTBLANK(BlanksRange),"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL((IF(BlanksRange<>"",ROW(BlanksRange),ROW()+ROWS(BlanksRange))),ROW()-ROW(NoBlanksRange)+1),COLUMN(BlanksRange),4)))
```

Enter it in C2 and do a fill down. Name the range B2:B8 "BlanksRange" and the range C2:C8 "NoBlanksRange". The two ranges must have the same number of rows (they don't have to be *on* the same rows, though).

Enter some values in the cells from A2 through A8. Try changing them. You'll see the lists in columns B and C change dynamically.

A sample sheet:

```
values    formula 1    formula2
1         1            1
2         2            2
5         5            5
2         ""           7
1         ""           ""
5         ""           ""
7         7            ""
```

The two double quotes represent cells displaying blanks

Comment: Thanks much! I marked the answer from Sux2Lose, since it does not rely on VBA.

Comment: @Jens: There's no VBA in my answer.

Comment: Uhm.. yeah. Stupid me, sorry. I was confused by the "You cann **also** you VBA to create a NoBlanks function" on the page you linked.