# Dynamic and alphabetized list of first 25 unique instances

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have an XLS file with a column `A` containing many name entries. It looks somewaht similar to the following:

[image]

I am looking for a way to dynamically create a list in column `B` of the first 25 unique entries in column `A`, and to do so in alphabetic order.

The result is supposed to look somewhat like this:

[image]

Of course I could just filter/sort/delete duplicates, but column `A` is subject to frequent updates and I need to keep manual steps to a bare minimum.

In a sense, I am looking for a function similar to [Google Sheet's `unique`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en). Hence my question relates to others asked e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/940837/excel-dynamic-list-and-count-of-instances) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/189737/dynamically-updating-list-of-unique-column-entries-in-excel).